# How to increase the frequency of data transmission of SIM900A GSM Module connected to Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm, iot, thingspeak

I have a SIM900A GSM Module hooked onto an Arduino Uno board. The Arduino is connected to a MPU6050 Accelerometer which is constantly monitoring data at 1 second interval. I am trying to transmit the gathered data to ThingSpeak server. I have successfully established the connection with the server and the transmission is occurring. However, the interval between two transmitted readings are very large, varying between 1 to 3 minutes. That interval is too large to use the data. Is there any way I can enhance the transmission frequency so that the data points are close enough? At least to a few seconds distance?

Comment: Just to verify, could you check if once per 20s works better? A free account will reject updates more frequent than once every 15s (showing HTTP 200 with a "0" response).

Comment: My thingspeak account is operated through my university granted mathworks account. It is a licensed account. The problem I am encountering concerns the transmission part. The module processes a whole bunch of AT commands then only gathers the data and send to server.

Comment: Start simple and add features as the simple things work.  Also, with out your code we can suggest little.  That said, create a version of code to send fixed data to the server and verify you can post data as often as you would like.  Many servers will throttle your updates if you post to fast.  Then add the accelerometer.  Get that working.  Then add the GPS.

Comment: Why not buffer 15 mins worth of samples and send them all at once?

Comment: @dandavis Your solution has crossed my mind and I did give that a go. But I could not make that work, mostly because of my lack of expertise. Can you point me towards the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be a complete description of how ThingSpeak throttling works.  However there is this text on the [Thing Speak License FAQ web page](https://thingspeak.com/pages/license_faq):

> As a reference, one unit provides the ability for a device sending
> data to ThingSpeak at once per second to send data to ThingSpeak for
> one year.

Assuming your code is working as expected and the ThingSpeak throttling is to suspend your service for 15 minutes, it may be that you are sending data faster than ThingSpeak will allow.

To test this, try to send messages slower than once per second.